# connecting two monitors to sun ray 3 plus

Tags: thin-client

I just recently got a 2nd monitor. It appears to be the same 24 inch monitor as my first.  The first works fine connected to the thin client (sun ray 3 plus). After connecting the 2nd monitor what else needs to be done so the 2nd monitor works. My companies sys-admins say it can't be done; I think they are having a bad day ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to install RandR 1.2 (X Resize, Rotate, and Reflect V1.2) on SRS (Sun Ray Server) to handle dual head output. For details check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E22661_15/MultipleMonitor-Multi-Monitor.html).

Just to be clear it is possible, I know as I use it every day at work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your thin client needs to have a second video card to support the second monitor. If you dont have that you can buy a dongle to support a video split using one video card.